# Can Save Draft be used more than once?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type with 100+ fields with lots of required fields. I am using the 7.x-1.4+8-dev version of the [Save Draft](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_draft) module, with the patch which allows saving a draft without all required fields filled.

It appears that saving a draft works only once. Is it possible to save a draft more than once?

Comment: I think 100+ fields on one content type is a sign you should revisit how your content is modeled. That sounds like a painful workflow that could be mitigated by breaking things up into chunks (e.g. Entity reference w/ entity inline forms).